# Only a poor knife cuts one way

Tags: story-identification, quotes, harry-harrison

A Science fiction book, possibly from Harrison's *The Stainless Steel Rat* series, includes a quote something like, "Only  a poor knife cuts one way" or perhaps "'Tis a poor knife that cuts one way".

The context is that someone is making a dangerous choice in order to accomplish a remarkable result.

What's the exact quote and book reference, please? I bet someone here knows!

Comment: [I see what you did there.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/321547/why-do-people-use-c-if-it-is-so-dangerous)

Comment: @MikeHarris heh nice. It's probably best to be able to actually quote the quote one is quoting. But single or double?

Comment: *"The knife of your cold logic cuts deep, Dad. It appears that all of
them employed, on the day of the robbery, the same circus act."* - The Stainless Steel Rat Joins the Circus

Comment: I've gone through all twelve Stainless Steel Rat books and searched for "poor knife", "that cuts" and "cuts one" and "cuts only". Zero matches found.

Comment: This sounds familiar. Cogitating.  May not be Harrison.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect you're thinking of Asimov's *Foundation* books. One of the Foundation's first leaders, Salvor Hardin, was fond of aphorisms, one of which was:

> An atom-blaster is a good weapon, but it can point both ways.

A later leader, possibly Hober Mallow, paraphrased this as "It's a poor atom blaster that can't point both ways".

Comment: Could be. I looooove Foundation.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Don't we all... Those books got me through my childhood